# Line deformation in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

By using paper.js, I wanted to create an animation of a curve deformation following the object moving along. This deformation should just be a simple change, like moving of the path handles in i.e. CorelDraw, but it should follow the moving object.

Here is the jsbin of my effort so far:

http://jsbin.com/luwosiniga/1/edit?js,output

The main issue is in lines:

```
var sigm_location = sigmoid_path.getNearestLocation(imi_logo.position);
sigm_location.segment.handleIn.x = 20;
```

Namely, I can see the segment point handle has moved, but the path shape remains unchanged, and it also does this only for the first segment. The value (for handleIn.x) in console output is 20. Any suggestions?

Also, if any other technique could be employed for this, it would be great to know...

Comment: Code has to go in the question, not on jsbin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've hacked on the jsbin you created and found a couple things.

I think the primary problem is that the line `sigmoid_path.smooth()`. If you comment that out the line deforms; smoothing the path gets rid of the deformation. Maybe start each event with smoothing the path and then deform the line. It also looks like adjusting the adjacent segments' handles might make a more pleasing deformation.

I believe you also want to use `sigmoid_path.add(newPoint)` as opposed to `lineTo` because you're adding segments one at a time.

My revision is here if you want to take a look at it: [jsbin.com/sukolimavu/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/sukolimavu/2/edit?js,output)

A minor note - I turn off the onFrame handler after it's traveled the length of the curve - it helps the performance when playing with the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot bmacnaughton. It was exactly what I was looking for.